# Set and then use variable inside IF statement?

Tags: php

Is there any difference between how PHP versions parse this (or will that make any issue somewhere), if I use such line:

```
if ( file_exists($x="myfile") && include($x) ) 
{
.....
```

are there any case when `$x` might not be set in `include` ?

Comment: It should always exist, setting a variable inside an `if()` is the same as declaring it anywhere else

Comment: I would advise against writing such code, if you need to ask such questions. It's… not very ready comprehensible.

Comment: *Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn't stop to think if they should.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every version of PHP that will work (Except maybe for php versions older than 4.4).

I've tested this out with the  [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) from onlinephpfunctions.